# Prevent overbooking during high traffic requests

Tags: sql-server

I’m having a problem with overbooking in a SQL Server environment. Our table structure looks like this:

Table: dbo.Trips

```
       Trip_ID   Trip_Name                      Trip_Capacity
       1001      Field Trip to Vegas in March   8
       1002      Field Trip to NYC in April     4
       1003      Field Trip to Miami in May     20
```

Table: dbo.Trip_Signup

```
       Signup_ID (PK)   Trip_ID   Person_ID   Date_Created
       1                1002      SKCIIEKF    02/08/2022 09:16:00
       2                1002      LKKSKEIC    02/11/2022 11:42:00
       3                1002      NCGSBEBB    02/12/2022 15:19:00
```

Trip_ID 1002 has a capacity of 4 and currently has 3 spots taken. We are setting a time, like 8am EST on 02/18/22, when users can log in and reserve the 4th spot, first come first served. The problem is that at 8am on Feb 18 hundreds of people try to reserve that one spot, and for some reason our process is allowing more than one person to create a record, resulting in overbooking.

The process should work like this:

- User logs in.
- If trip 1002 is not already at capacity then allow user to add to cart.
- User adds trip 1002 to cart, clicks ‘Execute cart’
- Stored proc ‘procExecCart’ executes, gets Trip_Capacity from table [Trips], checks [Trip_Signup] to see if a slot is available. If yes, then add a record to [Trip_Signup].

We always seem to overbook by 3 or 4 slots. The overbook records are created in those first minutes when hundreds of people are competing for the same record.

Given that we cannot change the data structure, is there a way to ensure that overbooking can’t happen, and that the remaining capacity truly goes to the first person who requests it?

So far we have tried to use NOLOCK on table [Trip_Signup] when counting signups in hopes that this would provide an accurate count of existing and pending signups. This has not helped.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

To clarify, we’re using NOLOCK to look for uncommitted INSERTs on table [Trip_Signup]. The proc logic looks like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.procExecCart
@Trip_ID int, @Person_ID varchar(20)
AS
– Check for availability
– NOLOCK is used to include uncommitted inserts in the count of current signups
DECLARE @Capacity in = (SELECT Trip_Capacity FROM dbo.Trips WHERE Trip_ID = @Trip_ID),
        @Current_Signup_Count int = (SELECT  Count(0) FROM dbo.Trip_Signup (NOLOCK) WHERE Trip_ID = @Trip_ID)

– Create a signup record
IF @Capacity > @Current_Signup_Count
    BEGIN
        INSERT dbo.Trip_Signup (Trip_ID, Person_ID) VALUES(@Trip_ID, @Person_ID)
    END
```

Comment: We need to see your code. NOLOCK is the exact opposite of what you need to do to avoid overbooking. You probably want SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: *"we have tried to use NOLOCK on table ... provide an accurate count of existing and pending signups"* What? This is like saying you put the clothing in a bowl of water to ensure it didn't get wet. `NOLOCK` would achieve the complete opposite here; `NOLOCK` will return rows regardless of if they are committed or not, can even return the *same* row twice if it moves while the table is read, and many other things. Where did you read that `NOLOCK` would help provide accurate counts? Where ever that resource is, it's *very* wrong.

Comment: If you have multiple processes trying to allocate booking slots *and* you have a specific number of booking slots, you have to **lock** the table to ensure only one process updates/accesses it at a time.

Comment: *..gets Trip_Capacity from table [Trips], checks [Trip_Signup] to see if a slot is available. If yes, then add a record to [Trip_Signup]...*  sounds like the potential for race conditions.

Comment: _We always seem to overbook by 3 or 4 slots_ A trigger can prevent that - solving a part of your issue. The other is most likely related to a "race condition" (a term you can search on) that you need to address in your booking logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't want `NOLOCK` here**, that is the *exact opposite* of what you need, as it may miss or double-count rows in many high-concurrency situations. You need *more* locking. I suggest you use `SERIALIZABLE` for iron-clad guarantees.

You would need an explicit transaction for your current code. But this does not actually need it, because you can do it all in one statement (every statement runs in its own transaction anyway).

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.procExecCart
  @Trip_ID int,
  @Person_ID varchar(20)
AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT dbo.Trip_Signup (Trip_ID, Person_ID)
SELECT @Trip_ID, @Person_ID
WHERE (SELECT Trip_Capacity FROM dbo.Trips t WHERE t.Trip_ID = @Trip_ID)
    > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Trip_Signup ts WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ts.Trip_ID = @Trip_ID);

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    THROW 50001, N'Trip Capacity Exceeded', 0;
```

> The `UPDLOCK` hint is added to help prevent deadlocks, which can be common under `SERIALIZABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Charlieface. I see how this addresses both the race condition and locking the table during the transaction.
Here's what I'm thinking the final code might look like. I isolated the INSERT statement into its own proc because [procExecCart] will need to iterate over multiple signup requests in the cart.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.procExecCart
@Trip_ID int,
@Person_ID varchar(20)

AS

-- Try to create the signup
DECLARE @Response nvarchar(4000)
EXEC procInsertSignup @Trip_ID = @Trip_ID, @Person_ID = @Person_ID, @Response = @Response OUTPUT;

-- Do some stuff: create a log record, etc.

-- Return the response to the caller
SELECT @Response AS Response

RETURN

-----------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROC dbo.procInsertSignup
@Trip_ID int,
@Person_ID varchar(20),
@Response nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT

AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT dbo.Trip_Signup (Trip_ID, Person_ID)
    SELECT @Trip_ID, @Person_ID
    WHERE (SELECT Trip_Capacity FROM dbo.Trips t WHERE t.Trip_ID = @Trip_ID)
        > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Trip_Signup ts WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ts.Trip_ID = @Trip_ID);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        SELECT @Response = 'Trip Capacity Exceeded'
    ELSE
        SELECT @Response = 'Your spot was successfully reserved'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  

    SELECT @Response = ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Comment: There should be no need for the `TRY` `CATCH` or the custom `@Response`, just catch all exceptions on the client application. `THROW` will raise an exception which feeds back to the client